How to create an interactive excel chart with multiple filtered values that need to result in a different final value?
I'm having a really hard time creating an interactive chart here on excel because of it's complexity.
I need to show in a chart, can be multiple linked charts as long as the filter on the first chart is what affects the rest, the resulting values of multiple contract analysis from different providers so i need to have first, a main chart that will shown the full value, than I need a filter for that chart that will show all the paid values and them, another filter that will show the final resulting value from what was paid and what was not, after that, I need another filter to show another value and them a final validating value.
Example Below.
enter image description here
The picture would be an example, would need a way in a chart
Would need a way to show in a chart the full value initially without being divided by contracts or providers just the full value and them through filters, the chart changes to paid value and them changes to pending value and so on.
Don't know if I explained it properly, but I appreciate any help.
i tried a lot of interactive chats, power pivot charts, linked charts but couldn't get the results I was expecting, I maybe doing it wrong though.
